# How is the Cello library able to introduce use of operators and keywords even though they are not part of the C library?

Tags: c

I recently came across a C library called Cello. I saw some examples of this library and noticed that it introduced some new operators and keywords. How is a library able to do so? How is the compiler made aware of such stuff? Also, how can I also do such things?

Thank you!

PS: The link to the Cello library website: [Cello](http://libcello.org/)

Comment: I don't know this particular library, but in my experience whenever you come across something that seems to change the syntax of C, it is usually done by abusing the preprocessor. I would recommend against using such libraries though, because they tend to make the code harder to understand.

Comment: Ohh. I thought there was something higher at play here. I guess I haven't really paid much attention to Preprocessors and ignored their power.

Comment: Anyways, thank you for your response.

Comment: Well, to be fair, you don't have to understand Cello's macros to use the Cello library.  As long as they work, you don't really have to pay much attention to the underlying details.  This is true of any library or framework; nobody studies the .NET framework or the Java platform in its entirety before they use it.

Comment: The C preprocessor can be made to do quite a few weird and sometimes wonderful things. However that's nothing compared to the C++ preprocessor which essentially provides an entire turing-complete programming language, running at compile time. Just look up the term "template meta programming" and you'll be amazed by the crazy things one can do with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Preprocessor macros

In general, if you wanted to add a "keyword" to C, you would write a preprocessor macro.  Take, for example, the `foreach` keyword.

```
#define foreach(...) foreach_xp(foreach_in, (__VA_ARGS__))
#define foreach_xp(X, A) X A
#define foreach_in(X, S) for(var \
  __##X = (S), \
  __Iter##X = instance(__##X, Iter), \
  X = ((struct Iter*)(__Iter##X))->iter_init(__##X); \
  X isnt Terminal; \
  X = ((struct Iter*)(__Iter##X))->iter_next(__##X, X))
```

At compile-time, the macro expands into ordinary C code.

Some "keywords" in Cello are simpler than that.  For example, `var` is just an alias for a void pointer.

```
typedef void* var;
```

**See Also**
[Cello - Hacking C for Fun and Learning / Daniel Holden](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVxfwsgO00o)

Comment: Thank you so much. This clarifies everything. I underestimated the power of preprocessors, I guess. Thank you, again, for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the video link as well.